# Select for update skip locked

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Не могу понять, на английском читаю, кажется что ничего дополнительного не делает не документированная фича skip locked в oracle 11g.

Объясните, какие различия с этой фичей и без неё.

Comment: Запрос вернёт только не залоченные строки. А что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: то что и обычный запрос возвращает только не залоченные строки.

Comment: Не совсем так, только с `nowait`.

Comment: Да, то есть c nowait, в чем разница между такими запросами и то и другое возвращает не залоченные строки?

Comment: Разница в том, что обычный запрос с  for update никогда не вернёт ни одной строки, если в выборке есть как минимум одна залоченная строка. Он будет ожидать пюка лок будет снят. Если добавить `nowait`, то он вернётся сразу же с исключением  ORA-00054. Со  `skip locked` он вернёт (сразу) только  незалоченные строки или `no rows`, если таковых нет.

Comment: ага, думал Nowait вернет строки. спасибо

Comment: Да, вверху немного двусмысленно написал, если бы он вернул залоченные строки, то какой смысл  `for update`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Разница между запросами с `for update`, с опцией `skip locked` и без неё, следующая:

- Без этой опции запрос не вернётся, если в выборке есть как минимум одна заблокированная запись. Т.е. он будет ожидать (*wait*) пoка транзакция не будет завершена в сессии, которая затребовала *lock*. Если добавить `nowait`, то он вернётся сразу же с исключением, которое может быть обработано.

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

- С опцией `skip locked` он вернётcя сразу же и вернёт только не заблокированные записи или `no rows selected`, если таковых нет.
- И важное отличие для работы с курсорами - курсор с `for update` заблокирует все записи, попадающие под условие курсора, сразу при `open`, а если добавить `skip locked`, то только те строки будут заблокированы, которые были действительно считаны в `fetch`, что позволяет ограничить количество заблокированных записей, или возвращать открытый курсор как результат функции с ещё не заблокированными записями.

Не документированной опция `skip locked` была в 9i и 10g версиях. 
С 11g она документирована, см. [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2066346).

В этом ответе подразумевается `row lock`, для `exclusive table lock` см. документацию.

Небольшой пример. В первой сессии:

```
SQL> select emp_id from emp where emp_id in (1, 2) for update;
    EMP_ID
----------
         1
         2

2 rows selected.
```

В другой сессии:

```
SQL>  select emp_id from emp where emp_id in (1, 2, 3) for update nowait;
 select emp_id from emp where emp_id in (1, 2, 3) for update nowait
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

SQL>  select emp_id from emp where emp_id in (1, 2, 3) for update skip locked;
    EMP_ID
----------
         3

1 row selected.

SQL>  select emp_id from emp where emp_id in (1, 2, 3) for update;
-- ждёт, пока в первой сессии не будет произведён откат
```